# How can a collision attack using MD5 be used to break WOTS

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, md5, hash-signature, one-time-signature

It is stated in
[Winternitz One time signature security](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53293/winternitz-one-time-signature-security/53327#53327) that MD5 is not safe for Winternitz due to collision attack. Given that WOTS generates multiple, say 32 private keys then hashing them a number of times to obtain 32 public keys. How does a collision attack from MD5 break the Winternitz OTS?  Does this mean I have to find 32 collisions of MD5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that, in the question you cited, the answer included:

> BTW: this appears to be more about the proof technique used to prove W-OTS, rather than the actual security; we can create MD5 collisions (invalidating the proof), however we don't know how to use those collisions to actually attack W-OTS-MD5; hence it would appear to be secure (but we can't prove it).

That is, we don't know how a collision attack would break Winternitz; we just can't prove that it can't.

Comment: "That is, we don't know how a collision attack would break Winternitz; we just can't prove that it can't." -- That's an amazing scientific remark